# Runtime error 91 when assigning array to table with single row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

I first assign a table data body range to an array `arr = tbl.DataBodyRange` which works.

When assigning the array back to the table `tbl.DataBodyRange = arr` works for any array with a number of rows greater than one.

When the array only has one row I get

> runtime 91 error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

I can't share the original file.

Comment: Likely the `tbl` doesn't have a `.DataBodyRange`. What does `Debug.Print tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing` return in the Immediate Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Table `DataBodyRange` to Array

**Bad Syntax**

- When you use `Dim arr As Variant` you are allowing `arr` to become anything (in this case it becomes `Nothing`). When you then use `arr = tbl.DataBodyRange`, there is still no error.

**Good Syntax**

- If you use

  ```
  Dim arr() As Variant
  ```

  instead, `arr` can only be passed an array.
- If you use

  ```
  arr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
  ```

  instead, if the range is `Nothing`, an error will occur. If the range is one cell, an error will occur.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TableData()
    
    ' e.g.
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange
    
    ' Prevent
    ' "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"
    ' when the table is empty.
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The table is empty.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    ' Prevent
    ' "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"
    ' when the range is just one cell.
    If rg.Rows.Count * rg.Columns.Count = 1 Then ' one cell
        ' Note that this is only possible if the table has just one column.
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Do your thing... e.g., increase each number in the first column by 1:
    
'    Dim cValue As Variant
'    Dim r As Long
'
'    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
'        cValue = Data(r, 1)
'        If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
'            Data(r, 1) = cValue + 1
'        End If
'    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```